# high numbers and their position

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement, max

I`m trying to write the program that will find first three highest numbers in array and their position.

This is my code. But for some reasons the position of two last numbers is 0 and I cant understand why. Can someone explain where is my problem?
Thank you in advice!

```
int main(){

    int idx1 = 0;
    int idx2 = 0;
    int idx3 = 0;
    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
    int third = 0;
    int num;
    int numbers;
    int array[1000];

    printf("Print the number of numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Print your numbers: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        scanf("%d", &numbers);
        array[i] = numbers;
        if(array[i] > first){
            third = second;
            second = first;
            first = array[i];
            idx1 = i;
        }else if(array[i] > second){
            third = second;
            second = array[i];
            idx2 = i;
        }else if(array[i] > third){
            third = array[i];
            idx3 = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", first, second, third);
    printf("%d %d %d", idx1, idx2, idx3);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is *supposed* to work?  Not just the result, but how it should arrive at it?

Comment: Shouldn't there be as many changes to `idx`* as there are to `first`, `second` & `third`?

Comment: janegodna, any negative values will not make the top 3 as the top 3 all start at 0.

Comment: When you do `third = second` you also need to do `index3 = index2`. And when you do `second = first` you also have to do `index2 = index1`.

Comment: It would be simpler if you just work with the indexes. The values are in the array, at those index positions.

Comment: If you never use the array after the data is entered, you can actually do without the array altogether.  Simply track the positions at which the values were entered — and you do then need to store the values.  If you use the array later, then you don't need the separate values, as pointed out by @WeatherVane; you simply index into the array.

Comment: Also, don't forget to terminate the last line of output with a newline.

Comment: General recommendation: You spare yourself a lot of typing if you include static test data into your programme, in this case a pre-filled array (e.g. `int num = 7; int array[] = { 12, 10, 7, 11, 13, 9, 8 };` and work on this one until you get the desired result. Additionally it makes you much easier to provide a [mre] here on SO, skipping all this IO stuff actually irrelevant for the problem. If you advance a bit further you can write a function fulfilling the given task (here: finding the three largest values) and provide multiple different test data to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in the if statements

```
    if(array[i] > first){
        third = second;
        second = first;
        first = array[i];
        idx1 = i;
    }else if(array[i] > second){
        third = second;
        second = array[i];
        idx2 = i;
```

you forgot to change `idx3` and `idx2` for the first if statement and `idx3` for the second if statement.

Pay attention to that as the element type of the array is `int` then the user can enter negative numbers. In this case your code will not work.

Comment: @janegodna: To account for negative numbers: Initialise your `first`, `second` and `third` values with the first three elements of the `array` and sort them appropriately, then go on as you do already; if there are less than three values you cannot find all three selected values anyway, so you might want to add a test for and add some appropriate error handling.